# filter(Importrange) with filter condition on value of cell and not a direct value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, filtering

Got stuck on this GSheets problem for a while.
My formula is working using direct value of a cell :
[working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gQLA.png)

But not working using reference of the cell C2 :
[not working2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlkjN.png)

Parts in black are the same between the two pictures.

I tried working around "VALUE()" of the cell but not working too :
[not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHQrA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your screenshots it looks like the numbers maybe text-based in your source sheet(from where you are importing)

1.check on the numbers in your source sheet using `ISNUMBER()`

2.use this formula in your destination sheet & see how it goes

```
=filter([importrange(x)]; [importrange(x)] = TO_TEXT(C1))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are right !
It works smoothly now.

Have a good day!